# passing data between controllers when https are successful

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance

I am trying to pass the data between controllers when each http request is successful. that said, here is a hierarchy

```
<div ng-controller="ParentCtrl as parent">
   <div ng-controller="ChildOneCtrl as chi1"></div>
   <div ng-controller="ChildTwoCtrl as chi2"></div>
   <div ng-controller="ChildThreeCtrl as chi3"></div>
</div>
```

loading data within each next controller depends on previous one, namely when http request is successful.

ChildOneCtrl:

```
function ChildOneCtrl ($scope, sharedService) {

   var chi1 = this;

   sharedService.getChildOneData()
       .then(function (res) {
            $rootScope.$emit('childOneDataEmited', res.data);
       }).catch(function (err) {
           console.log(err);
       });
}
```

ChildTwoCtrl:

```
function ChildTwoCtrl ($scope, $rootScope, sharedService) {

   var chi2 = this;

   var onEmitChildOne = $rootScope.$on('childOneDataEmited', function (event, data) {
        getData(data);    
   });

   $scope.$on('$destroy', onEmitChildOne);

   function getData(data){

       var chi1Data = data;

       if(chi1Data.uEnabled){
           sharedService.getChildTwoData()
              .then(function (res) {
                  $rootScope.$emit('childTwoDataEmited', res.data);
              }).catch(function (err) {
                 console.log(err);
              });
       }
   }
}
```

ChildThreeCtrl:

```
function ChildThreeCtrl ($scope, $rootScope, sharedService) {

   var chi3 = this;

   var onEmitChildThree = $rootScope.$on('childTwoDataEmited', function (event, data) {
        getData(data);    
   });

   $scope.$on('$destroy', onEmitChildThree);

   function getData(data){

       var chi2Data = data;

       sharedService.getChildThreeData()
          .then(function (res) {
               //to do some data manipulation
               console.log(res)
               console.log(chi2Data)
          }).catch(function (err) {
              console.log(err);
          });
   }
}
```

while this get the job done, the hierarchy is likely going to change, become deeper so I am wondering if there is a better way to do it so I dont overuse events ?

Comment: Yeah good you're seeing how this can be problematic.  You can use services/factories for storing/managing data in a centralized place then inject those into your controllers and let the service methods/functions manage the data.  The use case for events is if you need to have some decoupled communication between a set of components or need to broadcast something that many components may be interested in responding to (like the state change events, though they now use transition hooks instead) https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1

Comment: yeah but I want to call next api only if the previous one returned data, if it fails the next one should not be called

Comment: Why not just use 1 controller for all of this?

Comment: this was just a simple example of a hierarchy, these controllers are used for tabs and it’s much cleaner to use less code for each one. the actual data is dependable on one another on backend side so if some data is missing from the first one the second should not be called

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you share the data it self through the `sharedService` ?
After you get the data from first controller, just assign it to a shared variable in `sharedService` and in the child controller (second one) just set a `watch` for this shared variable.  like this:

```
function ChildOneCtrl ($scope, sharedService) {

   var chi1 = this;

   sharedService.getChildOneData()
       .then(function (res) {
            sharedService.sharedData = res.Data;
       }).catch(function (err) {
           console.log(err);
       });
}

function ChildTwoCtrl ($scope, $rootScope, sharedService) {

   var chi2 = this;

   $scope.watch('sharedService.sharedData', function(newValue) {
         // do something like calling another endpoint using http.
   });
}
```

I didn't try it, it may fail, but the idea is to share data throug service.

**UPDATE**
Another approach is to have two `then()` or more:

```
function sharedService($q, $http) {
   var service = {
       sharedData1Promise: { then: function() {} },
       sharedData2Promise: { then: function() {} },
       sharedData3Promise: { then: function() {} },
       getSomeData1: getSomeData1
   };

   function getSomeData1() {
       sharedData1Promise = $http.get( /* what ever is here */ );
       return sharedData1Promise;
   }

   function getSomeData2() {
      sharedData2Promise = $http.get( /* what ever is here */ );
      return sharedData2Promise;
   }

   function getSomeData3() {
      sharedData3Promise = $http.get( /* what ever is here */ );
      return sharedData3Promise;
   }

   return service;
}

function ChildOneCtrl ($scope, sharedService) {

   var chi1 = this;

   sharedService.getSomeData1()
       .then(function (res) {
            /* do something */
       }).catch(function (err) {
           console.log(err);
       });
}

function ChildTwoCtrl ($scope, sharedService) {

   var chi2 = this;

   sharedService.sharedData1Promise
       .then(function (res) {
           sharedService.getSomeData2();
           /* do something with data coming from the first child calling getSomeData1 method */
       }).catch(function (err) {
           console.log(err);
       });
}
```

Comment: watching an asynchronous callback? Can't you just return a Promise  (`return sharedService.getChildOneData()`) and resolve it with `.then()`? It might get into a _callback hell_ with chained promises

Comment: In the question he wrote a code that call the data in `controller 1` and maybe he wanted to get benefit from the data in it, and let the `controller child 1` do the other call.

Comment: I don't see how updated answer deals with dependancies, where 2nd controller can call `getSomeData2()` only if 1st controller successfully returned something from `getSomeData1()`

Comment: what I am trying to do, is unless some data from the first one is there say uEnabled == true the second one should not be called as it will return 400, the same goes for the next one. only if some condition is met from previous one the next should be called

Comment: @AlekseySolovey, in `then` in `ChildTwoCtrl` if the promise resolved then he can call `getSomeData2()`, if not, then do nothing or catch and show message.

Comment: @Dabbas okay, then `/* do something */` should have been a call to another function (?)